# SpeedBoost - Need a Timer Saying after 2 Seconds put the speed back to normal

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

i just need help with some code of using a timer in a movieclip... 
so this code will hitTest if char is hitting the mc and if it is then it boosts the speed of the character and unloads the mc... just i the speed part of it to be on a timer... so a certain amount of time after example.. 2 seconds.. the speed boost runs out and goes to the normal speed.. any help?

```
      onClipEvent(enterFrame) {

if(_root.char.hitTest(this)) {
    _root.char.speed = 14
    unloadMovie(this);
}

  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Help on Creating Code For A Speed Boost in Flash AS2 (Platformer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429757/need-help-on-creating-code-for-a-speed-boost-in-flash-as2-platformer)

Answer (score 0):

Where you have defined your speed variable, type this afterwards:

```
function normalSpeed(){
    speed = 7; // the normal speed value
}
```

Now, change your movieclip actions to this:

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame) {

    if(_root.char.hitTest(this)) {
        _root.char.speed = 14;
        setTimeout(_root.normalSpeed, 2000); // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
        unloadMovie(this);
    }

}
```

That one line will fire the function `normalSpeed` after 2000 milliseconds, which is the same as 2 seconds (you HAVE to enter the time value in milliseconds!).

Hope this helps :)